# Prove $a_n =3\cdot2^{n-1} +2(-1)^n$

Tags: proof-writing, induction

$a_1=1, a_2=8$ and $a_n=a_{n-1} +2a_{n-2}$ for $n\ge3$

Prove that

$$a_n =3\cdot2^{n-1} +2(-1)^n$$
for $n\in N$

Base Case: n=1

$a_1= 3\cdot2^0+2(-1)^1, a_1 =1$, the base case holds true

I.H: Suppose its true for $$a_k =3\cdot2^{k-1} +2(-1)^k$$

How do i proceed for induction step, am i suppose to use $a_n=a_{n-1} +2a_{n-2}$ in the induction step?

Comment: Guide:

check that it is true for $a_2$ as well. 

now you can suppose it is true for $n=k-1$ and $n=k-2$ and prove that it is true for $n=k$.

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh yes it works for $a_2$ and how did u get n=k-1 and n=k-2

Comment: That is the induction hypothesis. Suppose $a_{k-1}=3.2^{(k-1)-1}+2(-1)^{k-1}$ and $a_{k-2}=3.2^{(k-2)-1}+2(-1)^{k-2}$, try to prove that $a_{k}=3.2^{(k)-1}+2(-1)^{k}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOTE:** For this problem, you need *two* base cases, since the recursive sequence is defined in terms of the previous *two* terms. I'll leave that part up to you.

**INDUCTION STEP:** Assume that both
$$a_n=3(2^{n-1})+2(-1)^n$$
and
$$a_{n+1}=3(2^{n})+2(-1)^{n+1}$$
for some $n\ge 3$. Then, by hypothesis
$$a_{n+2}=a_{n+1}+2a_n$$
so substituting the values of $\,a_{n+1}\,$ and $\,a_{n}$ from our induction hypothesis yields
$$\begin{align} a_{n+2}&=3(2^{n})+2(-1)^{n+1}+2(3(2^{n-1})+2(-1)^n)\\
&=3(2^{n})+2(-1)^{n+1}+3(2^{n})+4(-1)^n\\
&=6(2^{n})+2(-1)^{n}\\
&=3(2^{n+1})+2(-1)^{n+2}
\end{align}$$
which completes the proof of the inductive step.

Comment: im confused why didnt u prove n+1 and how did u come up with that equation $a_{n+2}=a_{n+1}+2a_n$. Also why is Siong saying to prove for n=k-1 and n=k-2

Comment: @TheGamer I did prove that, but I just "shifted it over". Instead of proving it for all $n+1$, I proved it for all $n+2$, which is basically the same. Also, I got $a_{n+2}=a_{n+1}+2a_n$ because it is one of the givens of your problem. Finally, you need to have *two base cases* since the sequence is defined recursively in terms of the *previous two terms*.

Comment: y ru doing n+1, isnt it supposed to be n-1 and $a_n=a_{n-1} +2a_{n-2}$ this doesnt give u $a_{n+2}=a_{n-1} +2a_n$

Comment: @TheGamer What part of my answer are you referring to?

Comment: @TheGamer No, it should not.

Comment: @TheGamer Do you know [Complete / Strong Induction?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction#Complete_induction) That makes proofs like this clearer, e.g. [see here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1219960/242)

Comment: I made minor changes to the exponents in the 2nd terms of the last two lines, but feel free to correct my changes if they are in error.

Comment: i get everything except how u came up with that equation $a_{n+2}=a_{n+1}+2a_n$

Comment: @BillDubuque ik for induction, u assume its true for P(K) and u goanna show its true for P(k+1)

Comment: @TheGamer It is a given that $a_n=a_{n-1}+2a_{n-2}$, correct?

Comment: yes thats right

Comment: @TheGamer From that equation, by substituting $n\to n+2$, it follows that
$$a_{n+2}=a_{n+1}+2a_n$$

Comment: ohhh, wow also rather than doing n+2, can i just do it for n+1, so its just $a_{n+1}= a_n +2a_{n-1}$

Comment: @TheGamer Right. Did you find my answer helpful?

Comment: @Nilknarf can i do that or no

Comment: @TheGamer Yes, that's right. In fact, you could even go so far as to say 
$$a_{n+101}=a_{n+100}+2a_{n+99}$$!

Comment: @TheGamer The inductive hypothesis $P(n)$ is that the equation is true at a pair of neighboring integers $n, n+1$. So $P(n+1)$ means it is true at $n+1, n+2,\,$ Since it is true at $n+1$ by (induction) hypothesis, we only need to prove it is true at $n+2$ to complete the inductive step - exactly what is done in this answer. If you study complete / strong / course-of-values induction then you will gain a better understanding of this type of induction (above is a special case).

Comment: @BillDubuque Im stuck on this part $6\cdot2^{n-1} +2(-1)^n +4(-1)^{n-1}$

Comment: @TheGamer The first paragraph in [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2151704/242) shows how to rewrite the last two terms to $2(-1)^{n+1}$ and the first term $\,6\cdot 2^{n-1} = 3\cdot 2^n\ $

Comment: but is that same as $3\cdot2^{n-1}$

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider two real $r_1,r_2$ of sum $s$ and product $p$ then if $(a_n)_n$ verifies

$a_{n}-s\,a_{n-1}+p\,a_{n-2}=0$

Then $\exists\ \alpha,\beta$ such that $a_n=\alpha(r_1)^n+\beta(r_2)^n$.

It can be proved by induction, if we assume the formula verified for initial terms then

$\require{cancel} a_{n+1}=sa_{n}-pa_{n-1}=(r_1+r_2)\left(\alpha r_1^n+\beta r_2^n\right)-r_1r_2\left(\alpha r_1^{n-1}+\beta r_2^{n-1}\right)=\alpha r_1^{n+1}+\cancel{\alpha r_2r_1^n}+\cancel{\beta r_1r_2^n}+\beta r_2^{n+1}-\cancel{\alpha r_2r_1^n}-\cancel{\beta r_1r_2^n}=\alpha r_1^{n+1}+\beta r_2^{n+1}$

So whe you have an equation of the type $a_n=a_{n-1}+2a_{n-2}$

Then you start by solving $r^2=r+2\iff r^2-r-2=0\iff(r+1)(r-2)=0$

Whose roots are $r_1=-1$ and $r_2=2$.

So there exist $\alpha,\beta$ such that $a_n=\alpha(-1)^n+\beta(2^n)$

Initial terms give $\begin{cases} a_1=1=-\alpha+2\beta\\ a_2=8=\alpha+4\beta\end{cases}\iff\begin{cases}\alpha=2\\\beta=\frac 32\end{cases}$

And finally $a_n=2(-1)^n+\frac 32\cdot2^n=2(-1)^n+3\cdot2^{n-1}$

You can find more on this general method here :

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_difference_equation

Comment: One can also view this in terms of linear shift operators, i.e. write the recurrence as $\,(S-2)(S+1) a_n = 0\,$ where $S a_n = a_{n+1}$, e.g. see [this answer.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2151704/242)

Answer (score -1):

**hint**

Let for $n\ge 3$,
$$b_n=a_n+a_{n-1} $$

then
$$b_n=2b_{n-1} $$
Geometric.

Comment: You sure meant $a_{n+1} - a_{n}$

Comment: @Alex No, it is correct as written: $\,a_n\color{red}{+a_{n-1}}=a_{n-1} +2a_{n-2}\color{red}{+a_{n-1}}=2(a_{n-1}+a_{n-2})$ so $b_n = 2b_{n-1}\,$.

Comment: P.S. I don't understand the downvotes.