# Sequence Induction

Tags: proof-verification, induction

$$a_n=2a_{n-1}+3a
_{n-2}$$ for $n\ge 3$

Given $a_1=a_2=1$, prove that$$a_n=\frac{1}{2}(3^{n-1}-(-1)^n)$$

Base Case: $a_1=a_2=1$

Induction Step($k\ge 3$):
$$\implies a_n=2\cdot\frac{1}{2}(3^{k-1}-(-1)^k)+3\cdot\frac{1}{2}(3^{k-2}-(-1)^{k-1})$$
$$\implies a_n=3^{k-1}-(-1)^k+\frac{3}{2}\cdot3^{k-2}-\frac{3}{2}\cdot(-1)^{k-1}$$
$$\implies a_n=3^{k-1}+(-1)^{k+1}+\frac{1}{2}\cdot3^{k-1}+\frac{3}{2}(-1)^{k}$$
$$\implies a_n=\frac{3}{2}\cdot3^{k-1}+(-1)^{k+1}+\frac{3}{2}(-1)^{k}$$
$$\implies a_n=\frac{1}{2}\cdot3^{k}+(-1)^{k+1}+\frac{3}{2}(-1)^{k}$$

Im having trouble with the second term, i can't factor it out

Comment: How is this different from [your other question yesterday](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2360056/prove-a-n-3-cdot2n-1-2-1n/2360062#comment4862436_2360062)? Just because the coefficients are not exactly the same doesn't make it a different question.

Comment: @dxiv i didnt realize they are the same and plus im not asking for all the help, i just needed help with the last term

Comment: your first line must be $$2\cdot \frac{1}{2}(3^{n-2}-(-1)^{n-1})+3\cdot \frac{1}{2}\cdot(3^{k-3}-(-1)^{k-2})$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner but is that goanna give me the final answer that i want

Comment: one Moment please

Comment: but your formula must be $$a_n=C_1(-1)^n+C_23^n$$

Comment: where are these constants in your term?

Comment: u mean $3^n$ and $(-1)^n$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $3/2(-1)^k$ as $-3/2(-1)^{k+1}$ and then the second and third term cancel down to the required result.

Comment: how did u get that term

Comment: @TheGamer It's the last term in your last line.

Comment: ik that but how did u come up with the $-\frac{3}{2}\cdot(-1)^{k+1}$

Comment: @TheGamer I've multiplied the 3/2 by -1 and $(-1)^k$ by -1 and so have multiplied by -1 twice (so multiplied by 1).

Answer (score 1):

one can do it like follows: $$\frac{1}{2}3^k-(-1)^k+\frac{3}{2}(-1)^k=\frac{1}{2}3^k+(-1)^k\left(\frac{3}{2}-1\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left(3^k+(-1)^k\right)$$
note that if $$a_n=\frac{1}{2}(3^{n-1}-(-1)^n)$$ then $$a_{n-1}=\frac{1}{2}(3^{n-2}-(-1)^{n-1})$$ and $$a_{n-2}=\frac{1}{2}(3^{n-3}-(-1)^{n-2})$$

Comment: shouldnt it be $(3^k - (-1)^k)$, the answer in my textbook is $(3^k - (-1)^{k+1})$,

Comment: i have only used your last line